# Integration of Two Multiplied Functions

Tags: integration, functions

If we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)g(x) = 0, \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}
For a given $x$, $f(x,y)$ is monotone in $y$, and $\lim_{\rightarrow \infty} f(x,y) = 0$. Also, $f(x,y) > 0$.

Can we tell anything about g(x). My intuition tells me that it has to be zero. Am I right? How can I prove it?

Thanks

Comment: strictly monotone?

Comment: I wanna make it clear about the monotonicity of $f(x,y)$. So $f(x,y)$ is monotone on $y$ for a given $x$.

Comment: Yes, it is strictly monotone .. For a fixed $x$, $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} f(x,y) = 0$.

Comment: Integrated with respect to x or y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition seems to be wrong.

For example, if $f(x,y)=e^{-x^2-y^2}$ and $g$ is any odd function of moderately growth at infinity, then all conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

If f(x,y) = y g can be any integrable function that integrates to 0. If we take f(x,y) = y for x<0 and = y/2 for x>0 for example then we can take g to be anything that integrates to 0 using a measure of weight 1 for x > 0 and weight 2 for x < 0. So g can be pretty much anything if we make f really crazy.

Comment: Or if $f=0$ and then $g$ can be any function at all.

Comment: This is clear but $f(x,y) > 0$.

Comment: You should give all conditions in the question. Please add the fact that $f>0$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the question to incorporate all the conditions.